# Fixed DIV with shifting responsive DIVs

Tags: html, css

Have one I can't quite figure out... I'm trying to see if this is possible to do without having to use jquery or javascript. If there's no other option, then I'll resort to that solution.

I have an image gallery made up of inline-block DIVs, all fixed size of 197px width. All these image divs are contained in a container overall and allow the max amount of images to display in a row based on the browser width.  I want to add about the middle of this gallery a 100% width DIV that can contain a Google Ad. I would like to have this DIV so that a perfect number of image DIVs are above it completely filling the row. Because I don't know what screen size the user will have and how many images across will fit in a row, I can't count on there being 5 across, or 2 across, etc. So how can I have a 100% width DIV half way down the container DIV that can, responsively, always make sure that there's a full row of image DIVs above it? The gallery itself has a variable number of images... some as low as 10, some as many as 200+.

So basically, I want it to look like this:

```
[IMAGE1] [IMAGE2] [IMAGE3] [IMAGE4] [IMAGE5]    
[ GOOGLE AD DIV ---------------------------]
```

And if the browser is resized so it's only able to display 4 across, I **don't** want this:

```
[IMAGE1] [IMAGE2] [IMAGE3] [IMAGE4]
[IMAGE5]    
[ GOOGLE AD DIV ------------------]
```

I'd like it instead to do this on the fly no matter how the browser is resized:

```
[IMAGE1] [IMAGE2] [IMAGE3] [IMAGE4]
[ GOOGLE AD DIV ------------------]
[IMAGE5]
```

I thought about using a float, set to 50% down, but that pushes all the DIVs under it. I would imagine position:absolute wouldn't work as it'd just put the DIVs behind it. Anyone have any ideas on this? Thanks!

Comment: Was my post to any help?, and if not, what did I miss?

Comment: @LGSon - I added a comment to your post!

Answer (score 2):

Assumed your markup looks like this, you can do that with `display: flex` and `@media` query

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p37fnahu/)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;  
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 197px;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  order: 1;
}
.container .goo {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: yellow;
  order: 2;
}
.container .img:nth-of-type(n+6) {
  background: green;
  order: 3;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .container .img:nth-of-type(n+5) {
    background: green;
    order: 3;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 787px) {
  .container .img:nth-of-type(n+4) {
    background: green;
    order: 3;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 590px) {
  .container .img:nth-of-type(n+3) {
    background: green;
    order: 3;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 394px) {
  .container .img:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    background: green;
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>

  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>

  <div class="goo">Goo Ad</div>

</div>
```

---

How does this work:

First, `flex` has an `order` property, where you can tell in which position an element should appear, like how we always only could do with a fixed markup order, so here I set all `img` to `order: 1`, which practically means "same as markup order" and the `goo` to `order: 2` (last).

Second, and as a default (for wider screens), I set the rule `.container .img:nth-of-type(n+6) { order: 3; }`, which makes every `img` starting from child number 6 to get `order: 3`, which means "after any element" that has order lower than 3, which in this case includes the `goo` element.

Third, using `@media` queries, at certain break points shift from which `img` number should get `order: 3` and as such move last in the element display order.

*Hope this make sense*

Comment: OMG! A great solution...please eleborate it...m too excited to understand this

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Updated

Comment: @LGSon - This code works really well, however I noticed that if I resize the screen to really wide, the greens don't go on top of the Goo ad to fill all the available space. So you're left with a max of 5 red across on top and 5 green across on bottom. Would this mean that if the browser size can fit more than 5 across it'll just go to a new line instead of filling all the room avilable? Screenshot: [link](http://www.warbird-photos.com/temp/DivCapture2.JPG)

Comment: @PhotographerBritt: Check this fiddle,  https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/p37fnahu/1/, I added new media query's, commented, which you just uncomment 1-by-1, and add a new `max-width` for every screen width that fit yet another image ... or you set a `max-width` and `margin: 0 auto` on your container and have it all centered instead, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/p37fnahu/2/

Comment: @LGSon - Thanks, that first fiddle is closer! But I noticed while the green will now go all the way across, the red still says with a max of 5. How can I get those to fill in all the space? Screenshot: [link](http://www.warbird-photos.com/temp/DivCapture3.JPG). I'm hoping to not limit the max-width of the gallery container, as I want the most amount of images to be able to fill the screen.

Comment: @PhotographerBritt Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/p37fnahu/4/ ... you might want to tweak the max-width values, but it shows clearly what/how to do

Comment: @LGSon - Finally had a chance to test out the code in the live gallery, but there's one last issue... which since this relies on 'order' might not work. How can I get the Google Ad to be half way down the gallery so there's an even amount on top and bottom (or as close as possible)?

Comment: @LGSon - For example, here's one of the galleries: [link](http://www.warbird-photos.com/gallery.php?Airshow=2016-LACountyAirshow-2). Depending on your browser width, I'd want the google ad to take up the middle row going all the way across. When the browser is resized, that should shift the google ad row so the above row always has images filling all available space.

Comment: @PhotographerBritt As long as the number of images is known, you alter the `(n+4)` value in `:nth-of-type(n+4)`, so like in your given sample link there is 72 images, that value should be somewhere around half, `(n+36)`, and then adjusted with the media query to make the amount of images break even before/after the Google Ad. If the amount of images is unknown, you need a script to get that half value. ... well it can be done using CSS, though you would need one rule per possible amount of image, which kind of gets unmaintainable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, absolute positioning can solve your problem if you also use a `max-height` on your images and a `z-index` to place your ad in front - something like this?

```
<style>
.img {
width: 197px;
margin-bottom: 75px;
max-height: 100px;
clear: both;
z-index: 0;
}

.ad {
position: fixed;
height: 50px;
top: 120px;
left: 8;
width: 99%;
z-index: 1;
border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>

<div class="container">
<img src="myImg" class="img" />
<img src="myImg" class="img" />
<img src="myImg" class="img" />
<img src="myImg" class="img" />
<div class="ad">Google Ad </div>
<img src="myImg" class="img" />
<img src="myImg" class="img" />
<img src="myImg" class="img" />
<img src="myImg" class="img" />
</div>
```

If there are more than two rows worth of images, maybe use jQuery to apply the bottom margin to only the top row so you don't get extra spaces:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
addClass();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
addClass();
});

function addClass() {
var i = 0;
var width = Math.floor($(window).width() / 197);
$('.img').each(function(){
$(this).removeClass('topImg');
if (i < width) {
$(this).addClass('topImg');
}
i++;
});
}
```

**CSS**

```
width: 197px;
max-height: 100px;
clear: both;
z-index: 0;
}

.topImg {
margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.ad {
position: fixed;
height: 50px;
top: 120px;
left: 8;
width: 99%;
z-index: 1;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mt7godbb/2/

Comment: It seems to me this does what the OP asked for: https://jsfiddle.net/mt7godbb/ 

Why the downvote?

Comment: Photographer Britt dont want that div to be fixed even if we scroll the window...that div is also scrollable but not in your code. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7cxe3sek/;

Comment: @GauravAggarwal is correct, while this solution does work the ad is fixed. Since there's an unknown number of images in the gallery I can't set a fixed position from the top. The gallery could have 7 images or 200+ images. I'll give this an upvote, however, because it does move the image DIVs around correctly.

Comment: @PhotographerBritt is the jquery solution worked for u??

Answer (score 0):

I am following this question from 2 hours it's a great question. I don't think there is any with css or may be i don't know but i did it with some jquery.

Here is working example : https://jsfiddle.net/7cxe3sek/;

And here is my complete code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="small_block"></div>
    <div class="small_block"></div>
    <div class="small_block"></div>
    <div class="small_block"></div>
    <div class="small_block"></div>
    <div class="full_block"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.main{
  font-size:0;
}
.small_block{
  background:#000;
  width:197px;
  height:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.full_block{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:#ff0000;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var boxWidth = $('.small_block').width();
    var boxLength = $('.small_block').length;
    var longBox = "<div class=\"full_block\"></div>"
    var visibleValue = windowWidth/boxWidth;
    var visibleDiv = visibleValue.toString().split('.')[0];
    if(boxLength>visibleDiv){
        $('.full_block').remove();
        $(longBox).insertAfter($('.small_block').eq(visibleDiv-1));
    } else {
        $('.full_block').remove();
        $(longBox).insertAfter($('.small_block:last'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution is nice because it's cleaner code overall and does exactly what I need, even if it does rely on JS. The issue I'm seeing with the code is that when I load the fiddle demo, it starts out with the DIVs misaligned. Screenshot: [link](http://www.warbird-photos.com/temp/DivCapture.JPG)

Comment: Thats not a big deal that i can handle i just ignored because css solution already answered

Comment: The above answer might not end up working because it does not put the Google Ad DIV in the center of the gallery. Will yours do that? And how would I get that top row to correctly work?

Comment: It appears your answer is the same way. If I add many more small_blocks, they shift to a new line instead of going under the Google Ad and keeping the ad at 50%. Since there is a variable amount of images in the gallery, I can't know how where to put the ad. I suppose I could have it look at the browser width on the fly then (with php handing the image count to javascript on page load) using the image count make the calculations based on a 197px width to figure out where the 'middle' is to put the add, but I just thought there might be an easier way.